# Links between IPython notebooks

Tags: python, ipython

Is it possible to link one IPython notebook to another with a hyperlink in a Markdown cell?  If I try

```
Link to [Notebook 2](files/notebook2.ipynb)
```

or

```
Link to <a href="files/notebook2.ipynb">Notebook 2</a>
```

A new tab is opened with raw unformatted contents of the ipynb file.  Is there a way to get IPython to open another notebook for use in a new tab via a hyperlink?

Answer (score 104, accepted):

Since IPython 2 you may use exactly the syntax you first tried:

```
Link to [Notebook 2](notebook2.ipynb)
```

Comment: awesome. That answer should be top of the list rather than the outdated one above.

Comment: I think you added this without vetting it, this doesn't work

Comment: I've just tested this answer and it works perfectly in JupyterLab as well.

Answer (score 20):

It is now possible to do this with Ipython 1.0+ at least.

Just do:
localhost:8888/My Notebook.ipynb

Here is the documentation for this feature.
https://github.com/ipython/ipython/pull/3058

Comment: Good find, I'll give it a try

Comment: This won't work if you have a second instance of Jupyter running, or if you have something else on 8888 port. If that is the case, the Jupyter instance will be in the next free port available (i.e. 8889, or 8890).

So, if for some reason you start another instance of Jupyter, the notebook won't link you to the right place.

Answer (score 3):

From http://python.6.n6.nabble.com/where-is-the-code-to-generate-IPython-Notebook-URL-for-a-new-ipynb-file-td4996991.html:

You can access a json version of all the notebooks from  url: $host/notebooks

Here is a snippet that worked for me:

```
    import urllib2
    import json
    data = urllib2.urlopen("http://127.0.0.1:8888/notebooks")
    json_data=data.read()
    list_o_dicts=json.loads(json_data)
    for d in list_o_dicts:
        if d['name'] == 'test':
            print d['notebook_id']
```

Modify this according to your need.

** on further reading, I just realized OP was also seeking new notebook creation, keeping my answer anyway as way to work with linking existing notebooks.

One way to try for OP's goal is to run a script which will create a new notebook.ipynb file into the ipython folder where ipython notebook was started from. That .ipynb file can be templated from a new ipython notebook created from dashboard, with the name and id of the notebook replaced with whatever you are trying to link from your existing notebook. I have not tried this, but should work since dropping a .ipynb extension file into ipython folder does show it up in the dashboard.

Answer (score 3):

Remember that if your file name has spaces you will need to replace those with %20

eg:

```
[Numpy](Numpy%20For%20Python.ipynb)
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to akim's suggestion - you can link to any (py or ipynb) file using a relative link, starting with "edit", and and then from the directory where you started the server.

E.g. in a markdown cell, if I want to reference a file whose relative location (relative to my git repo, which is also where I launched the notebook server) is "./path/to/source.py", I'd add:

`[link to source](/edit/path/to/source.py)`

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this is not practically possible. 
The link would need to be to the notebook ID 
(e.g. */a1e2a88f-3b91-4a4e-8ca1-d4fd7240f750* for the one I'm working on right now). 
This is an UUID created at startup by the IPython server.
So you can copy the link from IPython Dashboard, but it will be valid only until you restart.

Comment: I want to add that it's not practically possible with the *current* implementation. This doesn't mean it will never be possible. Follow [issue 3056](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/3056)

Comment: As paul said a year ago, it is now possible thanks to a redirect handler, and in next version the url should contain the filename that will make the process seamless for end user.